# How to get stripe element in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, stripe-payments, cypress, end-to-end

I want to write end-to-end tests for web-application on Ionic with stripe-payments and have problem to type card number in stripe iframe field.

I checked [Testing Stripe Elements with Cypress](https://medium.com/@michabahr/testing-stripe-elements-with-cypress-5a2fc17ab27b) to understand how to do this stuff, but it doesn't work.

I have this structure of my HTML:

Screenshot of my structure:

[image: Screenshot of my structure]

Can you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: See answer by Fody here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883621/10222449. This is a working solution in 2023.

Comment: I used this fillStripeElement command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77047702/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cypress-plugin-stripe-elements](https://github.com/dbalatero/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements) plugin should work:

> This plugin provides a `fillElementsInput` that makes it easy to fill out Stripe Elements inputs without `cy.wait()` hacks or anything else.
>
> ```
> cy.fillElementsInput('cardNumber', '4242424242424242');
> ```

Comment: That library din't work for me, but it's outdated

Comment: Looks like Stripe has changed the form and the `data-elements-stable-field-name` attribute is no longer present. If you modify to look for `id` instead it works.

`const getSelectorForField = (name) => 'input[id="' + name + '"]'`

Comment: Not working for me even with the change using Cypress 12.8.1. I get the error cy.fillElementsInput is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
for an card number we could use cy.fillElementsInput('cardNumber', cardNum);

for an example if we want to use within a page object 
   getIBANNumberText(cardNum){
      return cy.get('.StripeElement').within(() => {
         cy.fillElementsInput('cardNumber', cardNum);
      });
   }
```

in this example cardNum is the parameter to get the input into the Stripe Element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code it is helpful for me to deal with stripe in Cypress

```
 it('Stripe testing practice with cypress', function () {
cy.get('.__PrivateStripeElement > iframe').click() // in cy.get() insert stripe iframe id
cy.wait(6000)
cy.get('iframe').then($iframe => {
  const doc = $iframe.contents()
  let input = doc.find('input')[0]
  cy
    .wrap(input)
    .type('4242')
    .type('4242')
    .type('4242')
    .type('4242')
  input = doc.find('input')[1]
  cy
    .wrap(input)
    .clear()
    .type('12')
    .type('29')
  input = doc.find('input')[2]
  cy
    .wrap(input)
    .type('123')
    // .type('{enter}')
})

});
```