# How to add data into Stripe during the testing my site in Cypress

Tags: stripe-payments, cypress

I'll try to explain my problem.
I do test on the site - `mysite.com`. But during the registration user should add credit card data. They can do it on https://checkout.stripe.com/pay.
This page is opened after click on Next button.
How can I add credit card data?
THanks

Comment: which cypress version you have currently.

Comment: I have the latest Cypress version atm - 10.3.1

Comment: And are you using Javascript or Typescript ?

Comment: i use Javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress 12.8.1 not working with Stripe Elements iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882883/cypress-12-8-1-not-working-with-stripe-elements-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and create a custom command like this.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getStripeElement', (selector, value) => {
  cy.get('iframe')
    .should((iframe) => expect(iframe.contents().find(selector)).to.exist)
    .then((iframe) => cy.wrap(iframe.contents().find(selector)))
    .within((input) => {
      cy.wrap(input).should('not.be.disabled').clear().type(value)
    })
})
```

And then in your tests, you can add this:

```js
cy.getStripeElement(
  'input[data-elements-stable-field-name="cardNumber"]',
  '4444222211110000'
)
cy.getStripeElement(
  'input[data-elements-stable-field-name="cardExpiry"]',
  '1025'
)
cy.getStripeElement('input[data-elements-stable-field-name="cardCvc"]', '123')
cy.getStripeElement(
  'input[data-elements-stable-field-name="postalCode"]',
  '90210'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but in our app Stripe is not opened as iframe. It opens as a separate page as a step in a registration flow. First 2 steps user is on testing page, but the third step directs him to Stripe page, and then after saving card details, user will be directed again to the testing page

Answer (score 0):

I had to create `cypress/support/e2e.ts`:

```typescript
// https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-Custom-Commands
export {};

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to get an element within a Stripe iframe.
       * @example cy.fillStripeElement("#Field-numberInput", "4242424242424242")
       */
      fillStripeElement(
        selector: string,
        value: string
      ): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
    }
  }
}

// https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands

Cypress.Commands.add("fillStripeElement", (selector, value) => {

  if (Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity")) {
    // https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security

    throw new Error(
      "To get stripe element `chromeWebSecurity` must be disabled."
    );
  }
  cy.get("iframe")
    .should((iframe) => expect(iframe.contents().find(selector)).to.exist)
    .then((iframe) => cy.wrap(iframe.contents().find(selector)))
    .within((input) => {
      cy.wrap(input).should("not.be.disabled").clear().type(value);
    });
});
```

Then in `cypress/e2e/helpers/payment.ts`:

```typescript
import { getStripeExpiryFormat, now } from "@util/dateHelpers";

export function submitPayment() {
  const expiry = getStripeExpiryFormat(now().plus({ years: 1 }));
  cy.viewport("iphone-6"); // https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport
  cy.fillStripeElement("#Field-numberInput", "4242424242424242");
  cy.fillStripeElement("#Field-expiryInput", expiry);
  cy.viewport(1000, 2000);
  cy.fillStripeElement("#Field-cvcInput", "123");
  cy.fillStripeElement("#Field-postalCodeInput", "54321");
  cy.get("form").submit();
  cy.get("[data-cy='congrats']").should("have.length", 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, there is a 3rd party plugin which provides the same custom command code as the one provided by Das.

https://github.com/dbalatero/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements