# How to test stripe elements with Cypress in NextJs app without extra libs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, cypress

How can I test stripe elements with Cypress. I am trying to target the Cart Input, Cart Cvc and Cart Expiry. I found two article that I tried to follow - https://medium.com/swinginc/testing-stripe-integration-with-cypress-3f0d665cfef7 and one that comes from stripe - https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress maybe first the markup:

```
 <section className="w-full" data-testid="credit-card">
        <span className="relative flex items-center justify-between">
          <ChipIcon className="h-9 w-9 text-midnight" strokeWidth={1} />
          <RssIcon className="rotate-90 text-midnight" />
        </span>
        <span className="capitalize font-anonymous text-midnight text-xs">
          card number
        </span>
        <CardNumberElement
          onChange={({ complete }) => {
            mustCorrectError && setPaymentState({ type: "InitialState" });
            handleCardInputStateChange(complete, "cardNumber");
          }}
          className="border border-white text-white p-2"
          options={commonInputStyles}
        />
        <div className="flex justify-between items-end mt-2">
          <div>
            <span className="uppercase font-anonymous text-midnight text-xs">
              cvc
            </span>
            <CardCvcElement
              onChange={({ complete }) => {
                mustCorrectError && setPaymentState({ type: "InitialState" });
                handleCardInputStateChange(complete, "cvc");
              }}
              className="border border-white text-white p-2 w-12"
              options={{ ...commonInputStyles, placeholder: "CVC" }}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <span className="capitalize font-anonymous text-midnight text-xs">
              valid thru
            </span>
            <CardExpiryElement
              onChange={({ complete }) => {
                mustCorrectError && setPaymentState({ type: "InitialState" });
                handleCardInputStateChange(complete, "expiration");
              }}
              className="border border-white text-white p-2 w-20"
              options={{
                ...commonInputStyles,
                placeholder: "MM / YY",
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <EuroIcon className="text-midnight" />
        </div>
      </section>
```

here I have a component and in this component I have three Stripe Element Components - Card number, Cvc and Expiry and following the above mentioned artcile I have created custom command

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getStripeElement", (fieldName, index) => {
  if (Cypress.config("chromeWebSecurity")) {
    throw new Error(
      "To get stripe element `chromeWebSecurity` must be disabled"
    );
  }
  const selector = `input[data-elements-stable-field-name="${fieldName}"]`;
  cy.get("iframe")
    .eq(index)
    .its("0.contentDocument")
    .should("exist")
    .its("body")
    .should("not.be.undefined")
    .then(cy.wrap)
    .find(selector);
});
```

The only tweak I made is adding index to target the iframe I am after (because cypress finds 5, it should 3 however, when I increment index above 2 it changes the error from not finding nothing within iframes body to not finding body). Even if I look for the div#root which is the most outer wrapper within body it does not find it. This is my test:

```
it("User can successfully purchase after filling the form correctly",
      () => {
        cy.getByData("credit-card").getStripeElement("cardNumber", 2);
        // AssertionError
        // Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: input[data-elements-stable-field-name="cardNumber"], but never found it. Queried from element: <body>
      }
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, you should not be testing Elements this way, by trying to automate "prefilling" the Card Element. Instead, since Stripe.js and Elements are a dependency to your project, you should stub out the result you get from it in your code by using a hard coded "test PaymentMethod" from [Stripe's docs like `pm_card_visa`][1] and use that to submit the payment.


  [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/testing?numbers-or-method-or-token=card-numbers#cards

Comment: hi @hmunoz thanks for help the thing is that i want to test the entire flow without stubs to have it really e2e tested and secondly after purchase the webhook is assigning order in cms to the proper user this way I will be able to differentiate which orders came from testing so this last step is vital for me

Comment: you can still verify which order came from the test by verifying that the paid order has an associated PaymentMethod object which is `type: card` and has `last4: 4242` as that is the `pm_card_visa` card which has a card number 4242424242424242

Comment: I used this fillStripeElement command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77047702/470749