# Cypress 12.9.0 Stripe Payment not working and possible new settings in cypress.config,js

Tags: stripe-payments, cypress

I am a beginner and I trying to automate stipe payment using cypress(javascript) in  the following website:
https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com/

I am trying to implement the solution in .js format

I have tried numerous solutions

1. Firstly I tried the stripe payment plugin
   [How to get stripe element in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019988/how-to-get-stripe-element-in-cypress)
2. Secondly I configured the cypresss.config.js settings

[I disabled chrome web security and other settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmHFM.png)

3. I then looked at various blogs and forums for possible solutions like:
   https://bionicjulia.com/blog/cypress-testing-stripe-elements
4. Currently I am trying to implement this solutio:
   [Cypress 12.8.1 not working with Stripe Elements iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882883/cypress-12-8-1-not-working-with-stripe-elements-iframe)

but i get the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WjYY.png)

here is the code in .js

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
/// <reference types="Cypress-iframe" />

import 'cypress-iframe'
import 'cypress-plugin-stripe-elements';
describe('Stripe Payment', ()=> {
    it('careerEDPayment', ()=> {
        cy.intercept({ resourceType: /xhr|fetch/ }, { log: false })  // suppress fetch logs 
cy.viewport(1500, 1000)
cy.visit('https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com');  

function getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, attempts = 0) {
    Cypress.log({displayName: 'getCardField', message: `${fieldSelector}: ${attempts}`})
  
    if (attempts > 50) throw new Error('too many attempts')
  
    return cy.get(iframeSelector, {timeout:10_000, log:false})
      .eq(0)
      .its('0.contentDocument')
      .find('body', {log:false})
      .then(body => {
        const stripeField = body.find(fieldSelector)
        if (!stripeField.length) {
          return cy.wait(300, {log:false})
            .then(() => {
              getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, ++attempts)
            })
        } else {
          return cy.wrap(stripeField)
        }
      })
  }
  getStripeField({
    iframeSelector: 'iframe[name^="__privateStripeFrame"]', 
    fieldSelector: 'div.CardNumberField-input-wrapper'
  })
  .type('4242424242424242')

    })
} )
```

Even after tweeking a few settings , it still shows 0.contentDocument does not exist on your subject.

Comment: There may be multiple matching iframes with your selector. Are you certain that isn't the case?

Comment: It works fine even with burn test, most likely the network connection is too slow. But you should not mix libraries in the same spec - there could be some interference between them.

Answer (score 3):

You just made a typo, look at the example - for the particulat page you test, the index is `1` not `0`.

```js
cy.visit('https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com')

function getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, attempts = 0) {
    Cypress.log({displayName: 'getCardField', message: `${fieldSelector}: ${attempts}`})
    if (attempts > 50) throw new Error('too many attempts')
  
    return cy.get(iframeSelector, {timeout:10_000, log:false})
      .eq(1)               // this index           
      ...
```